# Adding array to Jagged Array c#

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

I've had a look at both [ASP.Net c# adding items to jagged array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320453/asp-net-c-sharp-adding-items-to-jagged-array) and [vb.net assign array to jagged array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535967/vb-net-assign-array-to-jagged-array) but I just can't seem to work this out...

So, essentially, it's this. I have a function that builds a list of values from a query or two. I'm adding each value returned to a list then converting the list to an array. All is good

However, I now need to return two values, so a multi dimension array appears more suitable. Essentially, this is what I want to do:

```
        string[][] array2D = new string[2][];
        array2D[0] = new string[3] { "one", "two", "three" };
        array2D[1] = new string[3] { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
```

All good so far. However, I don't know the values that I want to plug in to the array at the time of array initialisation, so, this is what I'd *expect* to be able to do:

```
        string[][] array2D = new string[2][];
        //array2D[0] = new string[3] { "one", "two", "three" };
        //array2D[1] = new string[3] { "abc", "def", "ghi" };

        string[] deviceIDS = { "one", "two", "three" };
        string[] groupIDS = { "abc", "def", "ghi" };

        array2D[0] = new string[deviceIDS.Length] deviceIDS;
        array2D[1] = new string[deviceIDS.Length] groupIDS;
```

But it really doesn't like the last two lines, report it needs a ;

Comment: `array2D[0] = deviceIDS;
            array2D[1] = groupIDS;`?

Comment: remove the variable names at the end of the last two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already created arrays here:

```
string[] deviceIDS = { "one", "two", "three" };
string[] groupIDS = { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
```

So you only need to set references to these arrays:

```
array2D[0] = deviceIDS;
array2D[1] = groupIDS;
```